# AS3 Timer Class causing odd behaviors, black screen, not starting, etc - Full code available

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, timer

So I'm trying to use the timer class in a Flash CC AS3 script.

When the SWF loads, it plays this looping video. When the user clicks the video, it goes to the next frame where there are 4 buttons which play movies, and a timer.

The timer is there so that if the user doesn't click after a few minutes (in this case a couple seconds) the SWF returns to frame 1 and plays the looping video, once again, until the user clicks.

After adding this to my COMPLETE and MOUSE_EVENT event listeners...

```
this(root).attractTimer.start();
```

when I click on the video, it removes it from stage and I'm again presented with the 4 buttons.

It's at that moment I need it to start the timer once again. If the timer runs out, it needs to gotoAndPlay(1).

I'm banging my head on the desk with this right now.

Comment: This is the error message I get after the the stopRemoveVideo function is called (from output).. 

TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
 at MethodInfo-623()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I got it working.

The buttons that fire off the video, I was using...

```
this(root).attractTimer.star();
```

I didn't need to use 'this'

instead I used

```
attractTimer.start();
```